# Unable run ProgressDialog - BadTokenException while showind

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross, progressdialog, android-context

I am having a problem with a ProgressDialog thing in MVVMCross.
I am getting `Android.Views.WindowManagerBadTokenException`: while creating `ProgressDialog` via `IReportService` where I have context from setup.cs.

```
public class Setup
        : MvxBaseAndroidBindingSetup
    {
        public Setup(Context applicationContext)
            : base(applicationContext)
        {
        }

        protected override MvxApplication CreateApp()
        {
            return new NoSplashScreenApp();
        }
        public class Converters
        {
          public readonly MvxVisibilityConverter Visibility = new MvxVisibilityConverter();
        }
        protected override IEnumerable<Type> ValueConverterHolders
      {
          get { return new[] {typeof (Converters)}; }
      }
        protected override void InitializeLastChance()
        {
            var errorHandler = new ReportsDisplayer(ApplicationContext);
            base.InitializeLastChance();
        }

    }
```

```
public class ReportsDisplayer
: IMvxServiceConsumer<IReportsSource>
      , IMvxServiceConsumer<IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity>
{
    private readonly Context _applicationContext;
    private ProgressDialog _progressDialog;

    public ReportsDisplayer(Context applicationContext)
    {
        _applicationContext = applicationContext;

        var source = this.GetService<IReportsSource>();
        source.ErrorReported += (sender, args) => ShowError(args.Message);
        source.MessageReported += (sender, args) => ShowMessage(args.Title, args.Message);
        source.ProgressDialogShowed += (sender, args) => ShowProgressDialog(args.Title, args.Message);
        source.ProgressDialogDismiss += (sender, args) => DismissProgressDialog();

    }

    private void ShowError(string message)
    {
        var activity = this.GetService<IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity>().Activity as IMvxBindingActivity;
        View layoutView = activity.NonBindingInflate(Resource.Layout.ToastLayout_Error, null);

        var text1 = layoutView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ErrorText1);
        text1.Text = "Błąd";
        var text2 = layoutView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ErrorText2);
        text2.Text = message;

        var toast = new Toast(_applicationContext);

        toast.SetGravity(GravityFlags.CenterVertical, 0, 0);
        toast.Duration = ToastLength.Long;
        toast.View = layoutView;
        toast.Show();
    }
    private void ShowMessage(string title, string message)
    {
        var activity = this.GetService<IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity>().Activity as IMvxBindingActivity;
        View layoutView = activity.NonBindingInflate(Resource.Layout.ToastLayout_Message, null);
        var text1 = layoutView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.MessageText1);
        text1.Text = title;
        var text2 = layoutView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.MessageText2);
        text2.Text = message;

        var toast = new Toast(_applicationContext);
        toast.SetGravity(GravityFlags.CenterVertical, 0, 0);
        toast.Duration = ToastLength.Long;
        toast.View = layoutView;
        toast.Show();
    }
    private void ShowProgressDialog(string title, string message)
    {
        _progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(_applicationContext);
        _progressDialog .SetTitle(title);
        _progressDialog .SetMessage(message);
        _progressDialog .Show(); 
    }
    private void DismissProgressDialog()
    {
        _progressDialog .Dismiss();
    }
}
```

`ToastMessages` are working fine with using local context, but `ProgressDialog` doesn't. The debugger crashes while running `_progressBar.Show()`. I have searched all the internet but I can't find any solution. Any suggestions are more than welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is the same as [Android 1.6: "android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634991/android-1-6-android-view-windowmanagerbadtokenexception-unable-to-add-window) or [Error trying to open a dialog: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552581/error-trying-to-open-a-dialog-android-view-windowmanagerbadtokenexception)

> i.e. this line: Context appContext = this.getApplicationContext();
>   must go, and instead you use a pointer to the activity you're in
>   (probably this).
>
> I got bitten by this today too, the annoying part is the
>   getApplicationContext() is verbatim from developer.android.com :(

So, try:

```
private void ShowProgressDialog(string title, string message)
{
     var activity = this.GetService<IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity>().Activity;
    _progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    _progressDialog .SetTitle(title);
    _progressDialog .SetMessage(message);
    _progressDialog .Show(); 
}
```

Comment: Notice that [`IMvxServiceConsumer<T> and GetService<T> were replaced with Mvx.Resolve<T>  in v3`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16775765/23118).